# Touch list item only touches every other cell

Tags: ios, cucumber, calabash

I have the following step definition written with Cucumber based on Calabash. The name says it all: I want to touch every cell in the table view and go back to the table view again.

```
Then /^I touch every list item and go back again$/ do
    total_sections = query("tableView", "numberOfSections")
    last_section = total_sections[0] - 1
    (0..last_section).each do |section|
        total_rows = query("tableView", numberOfRowsInSection:section)
        end_of_range = total_rows[0] - 1
        (0..end_of_range).each do |row|
            scroll_to_row "tableView", row
            sleep(STEP_PAUSE)
            macro %Q[I touch list item number #{row+1}]
            macro %Q[I go back]
        end
    end
end
```

This works fine in a simple table view - but changing to a different tab containing a sectioned table view (A-Z) makes this script touch the first few cells and then it's getting weird: It scrolls correctly to the next cell but then it touches the after next cell until there is no visible cell to tap.

The only thing that is different between those two table views is that the failing one has sections and a lower row height. Why is it acting like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in using the `scroll_to_row` function. This is intended for simple table views which have only a single section.

The more general function `scroll_to_cell` supports both sections and rows. The syntax is slightly different:

```rb
def scroll_to_cell(options={:query => "tableView",
                            :row => 0,
                            :section => 0,
                            :scroll_position => :top,
                            :animate => true})
   ...
end
```

for example

```rb
scroll_to_cell(:section => 1, :row => 2)
```

For your case there is also a high-level function `each_cell`. For example:

```rb
each_cell(:query => "tableView") do |row, sec|
    touch("tableViewCell indexPath:#{row},#{sec}")
    #...
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Already got this covered in your Google group. The function `each_cell_and_back` fits even better to my desired behavior.